# Bundling and Minification Solution for ASP .NET 3.5 Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Is there a out-of-the-box bundling (minification would be also nice but not required) solution that can be used with .NET Framework 3.5 & ASP .NET Web Forms 3.5 ? Or perhaps a robust project that does it? I saw a few solutions like inside System.Web.Optimization but it does not work with 3.5.

Comment: hey there try this http://clientdependency.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , there is a library named **Cassette** by 'Andrew Davey'

http://getcassette.net/

Older version of cassette works for asp.net 3.5 webforms

Checkout the v1 documentation - 
http://getcassette.net/documentation/v1/

Comment: Thanks, but where can I download version that works with framework 3.5? One on nuget requires 4.0 and I'm bound to 3.5

Comment: for framework 3.5 , you can build the solution from the source code available as github repository                       https://github.com/andrewdavey/cassette.                       Remember to auto download nuget packages referred during build and choose the appropriate solution configuration.